# Collectionview Layout for images

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

how do I remove the white space? I want the images to be attached to each other [screen of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqZM5.png)

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 3 - 1, height: collectionView.frame.size.width / 3 - 1)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
   minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}
```

Comment: can you share a repo ??

Comment: upload demo to github

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be top-bottom-leading-trailing and set minimum spacing 0.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 3, height: your collectionviewCellHeight)
}
```

Download this link:

https://github.com/Shiju86/CollectionExample

Comment: you have to cross check your constraints.

Comment: I put the constraints that you say

Comment: @lukemier, I have just made a new sample for you. Please download the above GitHub link. Hope this will help you.

Comment: i see the project and the passage are identically but it doesn't work :(

Comment: if I can help you, my collection view isn't all the storyboard ma only in the view under the two buttons

Comment: You need a view same as you shared in screenshot.
At top of screen is imageView
and at bottom vertical collection.